# shell script to pass argument to input file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kubernetes, kubectl

I have shell script which takes some input from user and pass that input to the file which i am using inside my shell script

Shell script `myscript.sh`

```
kubectl create -f de_pod.yaml
```

here is `de_pod.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: test
spec:
    restartPolicy: Never

    containers:
    -   name: run-esp
        image: myimage:1
        command: ["python", "/script.py", "$Input1", "$input2"]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        stdin: true
        tty: true
```

this is how i am running the script

```
sh myscript.sh my1stinput my2ndinput
```

if you look at `de_pod.yaml` at line `command: ["python", "/script.py", "$Input1", "$input2"]` here i am using the user input after running my `myscript.sh`. but both `$input1` and `$input2` is not populating my value

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: If your shell script is really only that one `kubectl` line, then you aren't even mentioning those arguments in the script at all ? Also, even if that is corrected, it won't magically make those variables available inside the YAML file.

Comment: How would we know if you don't show us the script?

Comment: @Raxi, new to shell script , can you please help how i can do this?

Comment: I posted a possible way in the answer below.

Comment: @Raxi i am getting error ```did not find expected '-' indicator```. in your answer i see you have written ``` kubectl create -f -``` what is ```-``` here?

Comment: The `-` means standard input (`stdin`); it means the output from the command before the pipeline (`|`), which is the `sed` command, is used as inputfile; i'm pretty sure `kubectl` supports this syntax, did you perhaps try running it without the preceding sed/pipeline ?

Comment: Ifnot then you could change that line to this, which should have the same end-result:  `kubectl create -f <( sed -e "s/\$Input1/${my1stinput}/g" -e "s/\$Input2/${my2ndinput}/g" "${template}" ) ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i suspect you want is something like this.

**myscript.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ "${#}" -ne 2 ]] && {
    echo "Usage: ${0} <something_something> <something_else>" 1>&2;
    exit 1;
};
template="/path/to/de_pod.yaml";
my1stinput=""; printf -v my1stinput '%q' "${1}";
my2ndinput=""; printf -v my2ndinput '%q' "${2}";
sed -e "s/\$Input1/${my1stinput}/g" -e "s/\$Input2/${my2ndinput}/g" "${template}" | kubectl create -f - ;
```

If the values in the 2 arguments are complex values though, then some extra thought should be given to making sure they're properly escaped in the `sed` patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but if you want to use the pod deployment this way, then it should work.
To generate yaml files with different parameters, usually use Helm charts

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: test
spec:
    restartPolicy: Never

    containers:
    -   name: run-esp
        image: myimage:1
        command: ["python", "/script.py", "input1", "input2"]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        stdin: true
        tty: true
```

```
kubectl create -f de_pod.yaml | sed "s/input1/$1/g" | sed "s/input2/$2/g"
```